# In Postgres, how do you restrict possible values for a particular column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a column `element_type` in a table (called `discussion`) that allows the text values "lesson" or "quiz" but will generate an error if any other value is inserted into that column.

I understand that I could create a separate table called `element_types` with columns `element_id` (primary key, int) and `element_type` (unique, text) and create a foreign key `foreign_element_id` in the table `discussion` referencing `element_types`'s column `element_id`.  Or alternatively, I could forget `element_id` altogether and just set `element_type` as the primary key.  But I want to avoid creating a new table.

Is there a more straightforward way to restrict possible values in a column without creating a new table?

Comment: why do you want to avoid creating a table?  they are not particularly costly.

Comment: It's not so much the cost of a table as much as unnecessary clutter whenever I want to restrict possible values, which in my case, is very frequently.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You could add a [`CHECK CONSTRAINT:`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html)

```
ALTER TABLE distributors 
   ADD CONSTRAINT check_types 
   CHECK (element_type = 'lesson' OR element_type = 'quiz');
```

Although IMO the cleaner option would be to create an [`ENUM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-enum.html):

```
CREATE TYPE element_type AS ENUM ('lesson', 'quiz');
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. As a note to others who may be as new to Postgres as I am, CREATE TYPE creates a user-defined type to be used as any other type such as int or text may be used. In this case, one could say:

`CREATE TYPE element_type as ENUM ('lesson', 'quiz');
CREATE TABLE discussion
(
    type_of_element element_type;
);`

Comment: Worth noting that while you can add values to ENUM types as of recent releases, there is no graceful/easy way to remove them. If you anticipate your allowable values changing a lot, I recommend going with the check constraint.

Comment: We had a problem of mapping postgresql enums to Java enums and decided to move on with 'check'

Answer (score 64):

A shorcut syntax is :

```
ALTER TABLE distributors  
   ADD CONSTRAINT check_types 
   CHECK (element_type IN ('lesson', 'quiz') );
```

This translates automaticolly to :

```
CONSTRAINT check_types CHECK (element_type::text = ANY (ARRAY['lesson'::character varying, 'quiz'::character varying) )
```

Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This trigger throws an exception whenever someone try to insert or update a row with an invalid element_type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_discussion_element_type() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE new_element_type varchar(25);
BEGIN
    SELECT element_type into new_element_type
        FROM discussion
        WHERE discussion.element_id = NEW.element_id;

    IF new_element_type != 'lesson' AND new_element_type != 'quiz'
       THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unexpected discussion type';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
create trigger t_check_discussion_element_type after update or insert on discussion for each row execute procedure check_discussion_element_type();
```

If you want to remove the hard-coded types you can adapt it to check if the new type exists in a type table.

Comment: Very slow and complex solution, compared to a check constraint or ENUM.