# Protect column/key in SELECT call

Tags: postgresql

Assuming I have a (over simplified, non secure) table that looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, user VARCHAR(25), _password VARCHAR(25), email VARCHAR(80));
```

I want to add a additional failsafe on the column `_password` that prevents it from being returned on a `SELECT * FROM users` call, is this possible in PostgreSQL and if so, how?

I tried some versions of https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250991/929999, but this probably isn't what I was looking for. But that got me thinking that there might be a constraint that could be created. I can't find anyone who's tried this or asked it before, so I'm kind of lost seeing as I'm not a database expert by any means.

So for now I dump all results from the database into a custom dictionary placeholder in Python with a function called `.safe_dump()` that removes any keys starting with `_<key>`.

And I guess I could create a separate table containing a list of sensitive keys and match those on every `SELECT` statement via a `JOIN` or similar, but that would just move the risk of accidentally retrieving a *sensitive* key from the `SELECT` call to keeping that "`JOIN` table" updated.

Is there a flag in PostgreSQL that can filter out of block calls trying to access a key while still allowing it to be used on `WHERE x=y` clauses?

Comment: A view or a select rule

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess I could create a select rule in junction with https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/sql-select-all-columns-except-some that removes certain keys?

Comment: First, the password should not be stored as plain text.

Comment: @jira and second? And as a response, yes, obviously it shouldn't. And my original edit/post stated "this oversimplified table structure". I'll add that so  there's no confusion.

Comment: could you use row-column level security & grant select priv. to all but the `_password` column? or does the user executing the `select *` need the `select` priv.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deny permission for that column:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   "user" VARCHAR(25),
   _password VARCHAR(25),
   email VARCHAR(80)
);

REVOKE ALL ON users FROM laurenz;

GRANT SELECT (id, "user", email) ON users TO public;

test=> SELECT * FROM users;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation users
test=> SELECT id, "user", email FROM users;
 id | user | email 
----+------+-------
(0 rows)
```

If you'd rather want exclude the column from the output, use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW users_v AS SELECT id, "user", email FROM users;

GRANT SELECT ON users_v TO PUBLIC;
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `revoke ... from public`?

Comment: @klin I should have mentioned that I was connected as user `laurenz`... It doesn't make sense to revoke rights from `PUBLIC`, as `PUBLIC` has no rights granted on the table. I revoked the right from myself (the owner of the table), because otherwise with my default rights as owner I wouldn't have been able to demonstrate the effect.

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't make sense, just it seems unclear on the first look.