# How to put a constraint on the maximum number of times a domain value in SQL can be used in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to limit the maximum number of values that can be put in a table by a particular column.

So for example let's say I create a domain

```
CREATE DOMAIN pos VARCHAR CHECK (VALUE IN ('cm', 'cf'))
```

How do I create and/or alter the table such that there cannot be more than 2 'cm' or 'cf' (in the column where I use the domain) when making entries? Or should I implement that with a procedural language?

Comment: `DOMAIN` is used for (essentially) `CHECK` constraints: they only validate values within a single row: they don't compare values between other rows in the same table.  I think you want an exclusion constraint instead (see `EXCLUDE`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION )

Comment: Do you mean to say that there are multiple columns with the `pos` data type and only two of those columns can have a specific value for the domain? Or do you have one column and only two rows can have the same domain value?

Comment: @patrick the latter

Comment: @dai im still trying to wrap my head around the exclude syntax. Do you mind giving an example?

Comment: Please check for exclusion constraint examples https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_constraints.htm and https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/postgresql-development-essentials/9781783989003/ch06s03.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Postgres, how do you restrict possible values for a particular column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250939/in-postgres-how-do-you-restrict-possible-values-for-a-particular-column)

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit of an odd question here because if your domain has only two valid values and you can have at most two rows with any domain value, then your table can never have more than four rows. I am assuming here that your domain, or your restriction, is broader than what you put in your question.

You cannot use an `EXCLUDE` constraint here - as suggested in several comments to your question - because there is no way to determine how many rows there are with a specific domain value. Instead, use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger with a [PL/pgSQL trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Assuming that your table (`test`) has a column `position` of domain type `pos`, the trigger function in PL/pgSQL would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_pos() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM position
    FROM test
    WHERE position = NEW.position
    GROUP BY position HAVING count(*) < 2;
    IF FOUND THEN 
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSE 
        RETURN null;
    END IF;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[PERFORM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-GENERAL-SQL) is a SQL command that you can use in a PL/pgSQL function to perform or test for side effects, in this case to check that there are fewer than two rows having the `pos` domain value that you are trying to insert (`NEW.position`). If a row was found (i.e. only one row has the domain value), return `NEW` to flag that the insert operation can go ahead, return `null` to abort the insert operation otherwise.

Attach the trigger function to the table as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_test_pos BEFORE INSERT ON test
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION test_pos()
```